# Reporting with JavaBridge, php and Ireport

Tags: php, jasper-reports, php-java-bridge

I´m using javabridge and it worked perfectly when exporting my report from php. I´m following this site instructions:
https://github.com/tsuyu/jasper-report-php-integration
This is the code for exporting report in ppt format. (It is the demo of the link mentioned above)

```
case 'pptx':
         $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.pptx";
        try {
            $exporter = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRPptxExporter");
            $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
            $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
        } catch (JavaException $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }

        header("Content-type: aapplication/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.pptx");
      break;
}

$exporter->exportReport();
```

I need to show the report, in any format, as a preview in my web page, embedded in my site view, so users could see it before exporting.